# Can you travel to Portugal with a new passport and the visa in the old passport?

Tags: visas, study, portuguese-language

I was recently awarded an Erasmus Mundus Scholarship to study in Portugal and was granted with a Portuguese student visa valid until August, 2022. Before departure, I applied for passport renewal as it will expire in one year.

I just want to check if renewing my passport will affect the validity of the visa issued to me. Can I enter with my new passport and the visa in the old passport?

Note that it will be my first time entering EU.

Comment: Hardly an answer since I don't have a reference other than personal experience - but I've traveled many times with an old passport with a visa + a new passport. Both to the US and to the far east (I never needed a visa for the EU/schengen ) :)

Answer (score 5):

According to Timatic, the system used by most airlines to confirm visa requirements :

> Additional Information: Valid visas in full, invalidated travel
> documents are accepted if accompanied by a new travel document.

So yes, your existing visa in your old passport is fine, as long as you present both the old and new passports together.

"Invalidated" here refers to the fact that your existing passport will most likely be physically marked in some way when your new passport is issued (eg, by punching a hole through it, and/or removing the machine readable strip on the biographical page).

Although it doesn't say it here, this generally only applies if none of the biographical information on the passport has changed.  ie, the name, date of birth, etc, must match perfectly between both passports.  If your name on the new passport is different (eg, due to you getting married between the time the passports were issues) then a new visa would normally be required - although that does vary from country to country.

Comment: This is also my assumption. But I received an email from the embassy saying that I need to apply for a new visa in my new passport. I also emailed the Portuguese immigration to check. Still waiting for their response.